# Bootstrap equivalent align-right class like in Foundation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Foundation 6 has 'align-right' class to align menu item to the right, what is the equivalent class in Bootstrap 4?

Comment: Try looking [here](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/utilities/#text-alignment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pull-*-right is the Bootstrap 4 equivalent.